# i have a problem while running the code in pythonanywhere. It gives an error stating : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

[image]

So I tried to run my code in pythonanywhere but it's showing this error. I tried to install in bash console but it's still showing the same. I'm using Python version 3.8 which should support it.

I also tried installing pytube in the bash console but still not working.

Comment: How did you install `pytube`? And how did you check that it was installed?

Comment: `pytube` supports python3.8 fully well, in fact, I'm using it. check in which python version or any-specific venv you've installed `pytube` in

Comment: Pythonanywhere is a cloud hosted service.  So you would have to install pytube on the pythonanywhere server, not on your local server.

Comment: @matthias pip install pytube i don't know how to check

Comment: @JohnGordon how do you do that pls tell

Comment: @Evan Bose make sure you instlled the package for the same Python version / environment you run your web app with and that you reloaded the web app afterwards.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.